# How to write core logic waterfall callback for array of data in javascript (or) jquery without async.waterfall

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, callback

I have array of ajax calls which executes one by one. in between any ajax call fails it should fails remaining calls like waterfall.

```
var waterfallData = [{
    "name":"nodejs"
},{
    "name":"javascript"
},{
    "name":"angularjs"
},{
    "name":"mongodb"
}];

function wf(data,cb){
    if(data.name == "angularjs"){
        cb(null,"error");
    }else{
        cb(data,null);
    }
}

var finalData = {
    "dataCheck":""
}
waterfallData.forEach(function(checkData) {
        wf(checkData,function(result){
            console.log(result);
            return true;
        },function(err){
            console.log("error",err);
            return false;
        })
    });
```

Here it is executing as series calls. but i don't want to use async waterfall.

i want to stop loop if any case fails. can anyone help me on this.
thanks in advance

Comment: What are you expecting might fail - the ajax response or something else?

Comment: if ajax respose fails it should break loop (or) come out from loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **promisify** your `wf` function and iterate `waterfallData` using **for-loop**

```
function promiseWF( data )
{
   return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
      if( data.name == "angularjs"){
         reject(null,"error");
      }
      else{
         resolve(data,null);
      }
   });
}
```

Now you can use simple **for-loop** with `successFlag`

```
  async function waterFallInSequence() 
  {
    var successFlag = true;
    for (var counter = 0; successFlag && counter < waterfallData.length; counter++) 
    {
      await promiseWF( waterfallData[ counter ] )
         .then( ( result ) => { 
             console.log( result ); 
         }) 
         .catch( ( error ) => { 
             console.log( error ); 
             successFlag =  false; //make this flag false so that for-loop fails
         })
    }
  }
```

Comment: It won't wait for fail case and executes all success cases
output : 
{ name: 'nodejs' }
{ name: 'javascript' }
{ name: 'mongodb' }
null

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9vt4y50v/

Comment: Can you share a working fiddle/snippet/codepen etc so that I can see and debug there?

Comment: Actually i don't want to execute {name:"mongodb"} because it fails at {name:"angularjs"} itself https://jsfiddle.net/9vt4y50v/

Comment: @NaveenAsapu It works, check the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9vt4y50v/3/, you didn't used asyn and await as I had given in my answer.

Comment: Sorry i forget to mention. it is not working in internet explorer 11.
it is saying error  "SCRIPT5009: 'Promise' is undefined"

Comment: In that case you need to chain the ajax calls in more crude manner.

Comment: can you help me with internet explorer

Comment: @NaveenAsapu use a Promise polyfill

Answer (score 1):

If they're ajax calls, then you should use code with Fetch and Promises. Put the code into an async function, and then do:

```
for (obj of waterfallData) {
  const response = await obj.name; // or whevever you get the URL from
  if (!response.ok) {
    // the response failed for some reason,
    // break out of this iteration and do not do any more iterations:
    break;
  }
  const responseText = await response.text();
  // do other stuff with the responseText
}
```