# Make dynamically created promises execute in sequence

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

How can I dynamically create a series of promises and have them execute in sequence?

```
pseudocode
 for x=0 to maxValue
   promiseArray.push(createNewPromise(x))

 executeAllPromisesSequentially(promiseArray)
```

where

```
executeAllPromisesSequentially is functionally equivalent to

promise1()
.then(promise2)
.then(promise3)
etc
...
```

Comment: yes, you can do that by chaining the promises you create in the loop ... `.push(promise = promise.then(() => createNewPromise(x)))` - of course, you need an initial value of `promise` to start the chain ... say `Promsie.resolve()` for example ... it gets a little more complicated if you want to access the resolved values

Comment: Do all the promises only have a side effect or would you like to know the resolve value of them?

Comment: *have them execute in sequence?* You meant **resolve** them in sequence? since `promise` will be executed the moment it is created.

Comment: Check this one if it suits your requirement https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49606387/how-to-write-core-logic-waterfall-callback-for-array-of-data-in-javascript-or/49606880#49606880

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolve promises one after another (i.e. in sequence)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586110/resolve-promises-one-after-another-i-e-in-sequence)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some patterns displayed on my [gist](https://gist.github.com/muhammadfaizan/1461dc6f4d8f682af48cc5f0e7f5096b)

### Promise Iteration with Reduce

```
let tasks = [ /* ... */ ]
let promise = tasks.reduce((prev, task) => {
  return prev.then(() => {
    return task();
  });
}, Promise.resolve());
promise.then(() => {
//All tasks completed
});
```

### Sequential Iteration Pattern

```
let tasks = [ /* ... */ ]
let promise = Promise.resolve();
tasks.forEach(task => {
  promise = promise.then(() => {
    return task();
  });
});
promise.then(() => {
//All tasks completed
});
```

### Sequential Iteration Example

```
function spiderLinks(currentUrl, body, nesting) {
  let promise = Promise.resolve();
  if(nesting === 0) {
    return promise;
  }
  const links = utilities.getPageLinks(currentUrl, body);
  links.forEach(link => {
    promise = promise.then(() => spider(link, nesting - 1));
  });
  return promise;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just build up a chain as *jaromandaX* said. However you need to make sure that you use `let` inside the loop to closure the x:

```
  let chain = Promise.resolve();
  const promises = [];

  for(let x = 0; x < maxValue; x++)
    promises.push(chain = chain.then(() => createNewPromise(x)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Reducing or loop / recursion chaining comes to mind as a common practice however if you would like to keep and access to the intermediate resolutions here i have another approach by using an invention of Haskell's `scanl` function in JS.

`scanl` is similar to JS `.reduce()` but like `.map()` always returns a same size array holding the interim values. So the `scanl` function would look something like;

```
var scanl = (xs, f, acc) => xs.map((a => e => a = f(a,e))(acc));
```

So if you do;

```
scanl([1,2,3,4], (a,e) => a + e, 0) // -> [1,3,6,10]
```

So having `scanl` at hand now we may attempt to sequence promises by keeping the intermetiate resolutions in a resulting array.

```js
var scanl = (xs, f, acc) => xs.map((a => e => a = f(a,e))(acc)),
    proms = Array(5).fill().map((_,i) => new Promise((v,x) => setTimeout(v,100+Math.random()*1900,`res ${i+1}`)));
  
proms = scanl(proms, (a,p,t) => a.then(v => (t = v, p))
                                 .then(v => `${t} and ${v}`)
                                 .then(s => (console.log(`did stg with ${s}`),s)), Promise.resolve("init 0"));
Promise.all(proms)
       .then(vs => vs.forEach(v => console.log(v)));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
max-height : 100% !important
}
```

Of course above function is just makeshift. I use an unused `t` argument as a temporary variable defined in the callbacks context.