# Javascript Nested Promise not run in expected order

Tags: javascript, promise

I tried to simplify my code, in essence I have this:

```js
    function thirdPartyAPIMethod() { // Dummy method returning promise
       return Promise.resolve();
    }

    function func1() {
        console.log("func1 start");
        return thirdPartyAPIMethod().then(() => {
            console.log("func1 end");
            // ...
            resolve();
        });
    }
    
    function func2() {
        console.log("func2 start");
        // ...
        console.log("func2 end");
    }
    
    func1().then(func2());
```

I want to run `func1` and when it completes then run `func2`. So I was expecting the output would be this:

```
func1 start
func1 end
func2 start
func2 end
```

But instead it prints this:

```
func1 start
func2 start
func2 end
func1 end
```

Can someone help me to do this?

Comment: `func1().then(func2).catch(...);`

Comment: btw you never call `resolve`.

Comment: @RolandStarke func2 actually has some arguments, how do I pass them?

Comment: `func1().then((resolvedValue) => func2(arg1, arg2, resolvedValue)).catch(...);`

Comment: please look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49685980/make-dynamically-created-promises-execute-in-sequence/49686714#49686714

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your `func1` to invoke `resolve` after `thirdPartyAPIMethod's` promise has been *resolved*

```js
function thirdPartyAPIMethod() //dummy method returning promise
{
   return Promise.resolve();
}


function func1() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("func1 start");
        thirdPartyAPIMethod().then( () => {
           console.log("func1 end");
           resolve(); //invoke resolve here so that func1() is chained with func2 
        });
    });
}

function func2() {
    console.log("func2 start");
    console.log("func2 end");
}

func1().then( () => func2()); // then has function callback handler instead of return value of func2
```

Answer (score 1):

In the call to `then` of the first promise, you're not passing a reference to `func2`, but calling it:

```
func1().then(func2()).catch(...);
```

Change it to:

```
func1().then(func2).catch(...);
```

If you want to pass parameters:

```
func1().then(() => func2(...)).catch(...);
```

Or, using the pre-ES6 syntax:

```
funct1().then(function() { return func2(...); }).catch(...);
```

Besides, when  you define the promise you're not calling `resolve` and `reject`, so theoretically (except if you haven't posted all your code) that promise never completes:

```
function func1(...) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("func1 start");
        thirdPartyAPIMethod().then({
            console.log("func1 end");
            resolve(''); // resolve the promise with whichever value you want
        })
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func1(...).then(func2(...)).catch(...);
```

in above code func2() is executing before passing as input.

Correct way would be

```
func1(...).then(func2).catch(...);
```

P.s the following code is equivalent to what you want to achieve.

```
thirdPartyAPIMethod().then(func2).catch(...)
```